# Italic style for subsection title, not for the number

Tags: formatting, titlesec

I'm trying to give to the subsection title an italic style, but I don't want that this style is applied also to the subsection number. Is it possible?

I'm trying in this way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test2}
\subsection{Test3}

\end{document}
```

but what I have is this:

[image]

As you can see also "1.1.1" is italic.

Answer (score 1):

The unstarred version of `\titleformat` has more options, and can do what you want:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}{\upshape\thetitle\quad}{}{}
```

Here the `\upshape\thetitle\quad` part changes the font back to upright for the number only.

If you define multiple section types (*i.e.* also subsubsection) to have italic titles, it may be easier to specify that all ((sub)sub)sections should have their numbering upright with the following:

```
\titlelabel{\upshape\thetitle\quad}
```

Comment: You shouldn't add `\quad` to the second mandatory argument, but set the third argument to `1em`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalsize\itshape}{\textup{\thesubsection}}{1em}{}[]
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test2}
\subsection{Test3}

\end{document}
```

[image]